# How do I do Location/ProxyPass with Puppet's Apache module?

Tags: apache, puppet, mod-proxy, proxypass

I'd like to deploy and configure Apache using Puppet. I see there is an Apache module (https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apache), but it's not clear to me how to set up an Apache server to handle a large list of location/ProxyPass pairs, of the form:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

<Location /foo>
    ProxyPass            http://fooserve.llnl.gov:8080/foo
    ProxyPassReverse     http://fooserve.llnl.gov:8080/foo
</Location>

<Location /bar>
    ProxyPass            http://barserve.llnl.gov:8080/bar
    ProxyPassReverse     http://barserve.llnl.gov:8080/bar
</Location>


</IfModule>
```

I see documentation on virtual hosting, but it seems to me this is different. What I'd really like is to pass a whole bunch of location/URI pairs in at once. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `directories` along with `proxy_pass`, like this:

```
apache::vhost { 'x.y.z':
...
  directories => [
    {
      path       => '/foo',
      provider   => 'location',
      proxy_pass => [ { url => 'http://fooserve.llnl.gov:8080/foo' } ],
    },
    {
      path       => '/bar',
      provider   => 'location',
      proxy_pass => [ { url => 'http://fooserve.llnl.gov:8080/bar' } ],
    },
  ],
...
}
```

That would generate the Apache config file as the one you described. Another way is to have all the `ProxyPass` directives at VirtualHost level, like this:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

    ProxyPass            /foo http://fooserve.llnl.gov:8080/foo
    ProxyPassReverse     /foo http://fooserve.llnl.gov:8080/foo

    ProxyPass            /bar http://barserve.llnl.gov:8080/bar
    ProxyPassReverse     /bar http://barserve.llnl.gov:8080/bar

</IfModule>
```

In the Puppet manifest, it would be like this:

```
apache::vhost { 'x.y.z':
...
  proxy_pass => [
    {
      path => '/foo',
      url  => 'http://http://fooserve.llnl.gov:8080/foo',
    },
    {
      path => '/bar',
      url  => 'http://http://fooserve.llnl.gov:8080/bar',
    },
  ],
...
}
```